# Tree of Node<T> explaination

Tags: java, tree

Don't know if i am allowed to do this according to the rules of the site... but i will take my chance... please bear with me, i am only a student... :-)

I have a college assignment... I am having hard time understanding what the classes should do... i have gone to my teacher on three different occasions and the answer i got from him didn't help at all. Anyway the assignment details goes as follow...

Create a class called `Tree` that acts as a container for nodes. The tree class should support the following methods.

> **public void add(Node parent, Node child){}** -- Adds a new child node to the parent node
>
> **public void removeChild(Nodeparent, Node child){}** -- Removes a child node from a parent.
>
> **public Node getRootNode(){}** -- Returns the root of the tree
>
> **public void setRoot(Node root){}** -- Sets the root node of the tree
>
> **public boolean contains(T data){}** -- Searches the tree for a given type
>
> **public void dfs(Node child){}** -- Performs a depth-first-search of the tree and outputs each node (indented)
>
> **public void bfs(Node child){}** -- Performs a breadth-first-search of the tree and outputs each node (indented)

1. The tree class should be parameterized to handle a generic type T, allowing trees of strings, files etc... to be created, e.g. `Tree<String> tree = new Tree<String>()`
2. The tree class should implement the tree structure using an adjacency list and be defined in the following way: `Map<Node<T>, List<Node<T>>> tree = new HashMap<Node<T>, List<Node<T>>();`

The node class should also be parameterized to handle a generic type T and expose several methods...

Now i have written my Node class which works fine... and to be honest, i was sure that i have written a Node class which is creating a Tree. but after reading the Tree class description i am confused. What i should store in the tree Map. I am having hard time visualizing the whole thing.

Perhaps someone can explain what teacher wants and put me in the right direction. I am **NOT** looking for the code itself... just want to understand what i am suppose to do.

My Node Class

```
public class Node<T> 
{
    private Node<T> root; // a T type variable to store the root of the list
    private Node<T> parent; // a T type variable to store the parent of the list
    private T child;
    private List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>(); // a T type list to store the children of the list

    // default constructor
    public Node(T child)
    {
        setParent(null);
        setRoot(null);
        setItem(child);
    }

    // constructor overloading to set the parent
    public Node(Node<T> parent)
    {
        this.setParent(parent);
        //this.addChild(parent);
    }

    // constructor overloading to set the parent of the list  
    public Node(Node<T> parent, Node<T> child)
    {
        this(parent);
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    /**
    * This method doesn't return anything and takes a parameter of 
    * the object type you are trying to store in the node 
    * 
    * @param  Obj  an object
    * @param 
    **/
    public void addChild(Node<T> child)
    {
        child.root = null;
        child.setParent((Node<T>)this);
        this.children.add(child); // add this child to the list
    }

    public void removeChild(Node<T> child)
    {
        this.children.remove(child); // remove this child from the list
    }

    public Node<T> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public boolean isRoot()
    {
        // check to see if the root is null if yes then return true else return false
        return this.root != null;     
    }

    public void setRoot(Node<T> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public Node<T> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public T getItem() {
        return child;
    }

    public void setItem(T child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    public boolean hasChildren()
    {
        return this.children.size()>0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Node<T>[] children()
    {
        return (Node<T>[]) children.toArray(new Node[children.size()]);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked"})
    public Node<T>[] getSiblings()
    {
        if(this.isRoot()!=false && parent==null)
        {
            System.out.println("this is root or there are no siblings");
            return null;
        }
        else{
            List<Node<T>> siblings = new ArrayList<Node<T>>((Collection<? extends Node<T>>) Arrays.asList(new Node[this.parent.children.size()]));  
            Collections.copy(siblings, this.parent.children);  
            siblings.remove(this);
            return siblings.toArray(new Node[siblings.size()]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Bare" with you?  I'm keeping my clothes on - it's "bear with me."

Comment: One useful distinction to make: Are you dealing with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) kind of tree, or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) kind of tree? I'd have guessed the former, but the requirement to use an adjacency list suggests the latter.

Comment: I think the 1st link you have provided looks pretty close to what we have been given lectured on...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the map for the following thing:

The key of the hashmap is a given node, and the value of the hashmap are the child nodes for the given node.

```
public class Tree<T> {
    private Node<T> rootNode;
    private HashMap<Node<T>, List<Node<T>> tree;

    //and then some kind of function to go through the tree.
    public void expandNode(Node<T> node) {
        if (tree.get(node) == null) {
            System.out.println(node);
            return;
        }
        for(Node<T> n : tree.get(node)) {
            System.out.println(node);
            expandNode(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Could I make it clear how the tree works??

Comment: hmmmm
in my Node class i have made a method which returns the children in an array.... so what i should do, put the node<t> as key and children of the node as an array...?

Comment: Think it this way, the hash map is the whole tree, you may keep for yourself a refference to the root node, then it works like this, having a given node, you call the get mehtod of the hash map to get the children of that node, so then you can iterate over the children and use the same map to keep on retrieving the children of the nodes, when the get method returns null, then you have leaf nodes.

Comment: Also another detail, to make it work, you should implement equals and hashcode methods into your Node class.

Comment: hmmm... well, i think i will work on the idea you have given me... and will implement the hashcode and the equals method in my node class... but as per i don't know what Type of Object i am going to store in the node... on what bases i can generate my hashcode?  and the equals method?#

Comment: You could call hashCode on the hosted object since that is a method inherited from the Object class

Comment: about 2 weeks ago i was reading about the hashcode and i remember it vaguely now... but i will take a shot at it...

Comment: Man you have been a great help... i will mark my post as answered but would love to get more ideas.... thank you very very much

Comment: Equals and hash code are important if you want collections to work properly, for example sets use them to ensure that no duplicate elements can be added, a hash map use them to ensure no duplicate keys and so on.

Comment: you have put me in a direction... which is good enough for now... will contact you again if i needed it... just in case... if you don't mind... thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the 2 points in the list, I'm going to guess that point number 1 is the most confusing to you.

The tree itself can be parameterized.  The type parameter on the tree class can be used inside an inner class that is used to create the nodes.  That is to say, for the purposes of your assignment, the node class should probably be inside the Tree class so that it can use the T type parameter given to the Tree class.

That way, the tree can store anything (strings, files, Doubles, etc).  The Node class simply acts as a nice way to store any type T object.

Comment: you are right about the confusion part... :-) In description we are asked to write a separate class for nodes... which i have written

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit strange. If I were doing this and the assignment didn't say otherwise, I probably wouldn't write a Tree class at all; I'd just use Node as a recursive data structure, and have the root node of a tree represent the entire tree.

Since it doesn't look like you're supposed to do this, you could just make `Tree<T>` a wrapper class that has a reference to a single `Node<T>` object. You can put the logic for the required methods in either class.

The beginning of the code could look something like this:

```
public class Tree<T> {

    private Node<T> root;

    public Tree(Node<T> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

}
```

Comment: the description clearly states that the Tree class should support the methods i wrote in my original post... but can you give me an example of the initializing statement for a Tree class...? Please... Just trying to get my head around what you said... This other gentleman Juan is making a lot of sense too...

Comment: that is exactly how i started writing the Tree class but then got confused over the whole Map issue...

Comment: Ach, never mind, I've been thinking about this all wrong. I assumed that the edges were supposed to be part of the node's state. They're not.